# the difference between initialize an object with null or it's default constructor

Tags: java, constructor, null

Let's assume that we have a Class and it **contains only one instance variable** and **its type is reference type**. We did not implement any constructor, so the Class has its default constructor.

If I correctly understand, the default constructor gives a default value to the instance variables and the default value for reference types is null. Is that true?

If yes, we want to create an object of this class. Is there any difference between these two statements for declaring and initializing an object of this Class?

```
Class object = null;
```

and

```
Class object = new Class();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any difference between these two statements for declare and initialize an object of this class???
>
> ```
> Class object = null;
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> Class object = new Class();
> ```

The first one **doesn't** initialize an object of the class, it just declares a variable and assigns `null` to it. There is no instance, and so there are no instance fields.

The second one initializes an instance of the class, and so initializes any instance field(s) it has. If any of those fields are references, and you haven't implemented a constructor, they will be initialized to `null`.

Let's use a concrete example:

```
class Foo {
    String str;
}
```

Since `str` is a reference, if we create instances of `Foo`, `str` will be initialized to `null`.

Your first statement (changing `Class` => `Foo` and `object` => `f` to avoid confusion):

```
Foo f = null;
```

...results in this in memory:

```
+----------------+
| f (a variable) |
+----------------+
| null           |
+----------------+
```

Your second statement:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

...gives us something very different:

```
+----------------+
| f (a variable) |
+----------------+     +--------------+
| (ref #412785)  |---->| Foo instance |
+----------------+     +--------------+
                       | str: null    |
                       +--------------+
```

Comment: @ T.J Crowder : tnx for your complete answer